# JS - Functions don't work after importing VAR from different file

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, export

I have the following code on 2 dif

```
//file 1 expVar.js
export var myVar = [ //content ];


//file 2 impVar.js
import myVar from '../PathToFile';
```

And when I try to write a function in file 2 after importing it dictates that the function is declared but never read. (I use it on an HTML file) For example:

```
//file 2 impVar.js
import myVar from '../PathToFile';        
function write(){ 
}  //DOESNT WORK returns "Function is declared but never read"
```

But it doesnt return that error if I don't use import. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: did you try

export default var myVar = [ ... ]; 

or 

import { myVar } from '../PathToFile';

??

Answer (score 0):

An important point that you may not have considered, is that you just can `import` and `export` from modules:

[image: bad import and export errors]

**Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

**Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**

These are errors you will see when using them in **pure js**.

So what should we do?

#### First: We can change our files from `filename.js` into `filename.module.js`.

#### Second: We can set their type in our HTML file. so we have :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="./firstfile.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="./secondfile.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: you should `import` your variable with curly braces like:

```js
import { myVar } from '../PathToFile';
```

**OR**


export that as `default`. so:

```js
export default myVar = [ //content ];
```

All of my talks just was about your problem with import and export, but your main problem is that you didn't call your function :)

just use `write()` at the end of your file to call it, and your browser doesn't say: *`Function is declared but never read`*.

Comment: I did call it on a HTML file. I have a HTML file with a link to the JS file and it works fine if I just use the VAR on that main JS file. I'm trying to organize things better because the array has ~1300 lines. I can't still get it to work with all that

Comment: @MMelo31 can you share with me a fiddle that I see what's your mean?!!?
I can't understand what's your main problem.